# parse data from one field into others in filemaker

Tags: scripting, filemaker

I am working with filemaker pro and I am looking to get some text parsed between multiple fields.

I have a barcode scanner that is set to keyboard mode, so it essentially types very fast. I what to be able to scan a barcode into a dedicated "barcode parser" field and have a script parse that text into the "correct" field. eg. the data on the barcode is "XCX0001-user", so I would scan the barcode into the parser field then have a separate field named "user" be populated with "XCX0001".

I am not looking for a full script, just some ideas on which functions would work best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go with a dedicated calculation field in your table that automatically parses the user from the input field, or a script if you so choose. Functions you could use could be:

`Position(text;searchString;start;occurrence)`, which tells you where in a text a certain string occurs,

`Length(field)`, which gives you the length in characters,

`Middle(text;start;numberOfCharacters)`, which allows you to extract part of a string based on position and so on.

Check out other Text functions from the function list as there are many that can parse text.

Comment: This looks like the right track, thanks. I am able to get the correct information by using 'Left ( Barcode Parser Field ; 7)' to grab the user ID, but how do i move that to the correct field?

Comment: In it’s simplest form, just make a calculation field with that exact calculation and you’re set.

Comment: I see, i set the field I want to be the calculation field and have it call the parser field. Okay I got it to work!  Now the only problem is that the data disappears when I delete the "Barcode parser" field. What command would i need to put in at the end of the field calculation to prevent it from being deleted when I delete the text in the Barcode Parser? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To extract the `"XCX0001"` part from `"XCX0001-user"`, you could use =

```
LeftWords ( YourBarcodeField ; 1 )
```

This could be a formula for a calculation field, or auto-entered as a calculated value into a text field (in case you want to be able to modify it later).

To set the field by script, you could do:

```
Set Field [ YourTable::YourTargetField ; LeftWords ( YourTable::YourBarcodeField ; 1 ) ]
```

---

Note that this assumes the `-` hyphen will always be the only word separator in the scanned barcode.